# How to achieve Multiple drill down using the Axis Labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts, highcharts

I want to drill down using the Axis Labels in the high charts i achieved multiple drill down using the bars but i cant achieve using the access labels

How i can achieve it,

here is my fiddle

**[DEMO][1]**

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedmusthafac/d6fw7/
```

Comment: -1 You managed to achieve it in the demo you posted on the question yesterday  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24909498/3d-high-charts-multiple-series-inside-of-drilldown

Comment: But still i am failing in Axis Name what to do @Rob

Comment: Look at your demo here http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedmusthafac/x5E2Y/1/ there you can click on the axis categories successfully.

Comment: But the same thing if i implemented here it is not working for me

Comment: Your fiddle is a mess - learn to use the `TidyUp` and `JSHint` buttons.  Your data is also a mess.  Start with clean data like in your first demo and then build on slowly from there.  This really is not a worthy question.

Comment: Sorry @rob i made u irritated, i ll not repeat this from next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/d6fw7/2/)**

You need to add this code to make x-axis label clickable with formatting (underline):

```
(function (H) {
        //For X-axis labels
        H.wrap(H.Point.prototype, 'init', function (proceed, series, options, x) {
            var point = proceed.call(this, series, options, x),
                chart = series.chart,
                tick = series.xAxis && series.xAxis.ticks[x],
                tickLabel = tick && tick.label;
            //console.log("series");
            //console.log(series);
            console.log("Point = ");
            console.log(point);

            if (point.drilldown) {

                if (tickLabel) {
                    if (!tickLabel._basicStyle) {
                        tickLabel._basicStyle = tickLabel.element.getAttribute('style');
                    }
                    tickLabel.addClass('highcharts-drilldown-axis-label').css({
                        'text-decoration': 'underline',
                        'font-weight': 'normal',
                        'cursor': 'pointer',
                        'color':'brown'
                        }).on('click', function (){
                        //alert('clicked');
                        //point.doDrilldown();  
                                                                                                      point.firePointEvent('click');

                        }); 
                }
            } 
            else if (tickLabel && tickLabel._basicStyle) 
            {
            }

            return point;
        });
    })(Highcharts);
```

Comment: This is a solution but shouldn't be strictly necessary look at the simple example the OP posted to a similar question yesterday http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedmusthafac/x5E2Y/1/

Comment: You are right, but the author of this question is creating the chart by adding the by not adding the data directly, he is adding the data by using `addSeries` function which is causing the link on the x-axis labels not to appear !

Comment: +1 - agreed.  Author is a pain!

Comment: @Rahul the main thing is your script is working well but while clicking the label it is going to categories2 directly and accessing the categories2 data , but is there any way to make the labels to reach the categories3 something like that??

Comment: Well, I don't think so ! The drilldown process has to go stage wise !

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for the help i pointed categories3 three separately for the Axis Labels, thank you for ur help, if there is any help i ll get back to you